# setAttribute Issue

Tags: models, records

I have a controller function creating attributes for a model from posted data and sending them to a service to save the data.

Everything seems to be working correctly if I do a print_r in the service function before using setAttributes it is returning the posted data correctly with the changed attribute value. However when I use

```
$record->setAttributes($model->getAttributes());
```

The array that is printed after is using the database values so it is not setting the new attribute as the function suggests.

I have read other posts which suggest there may be a bug with the setAttributes function and a work around setting each post item individually (not ideal) plus I have tried this and it produces the same result.

Am I missing something obvious as to why the setAttributes is not updating the $record variable with the new $model attributes?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you/how are you validating the values?
What I found was that it was a validation issue. If a value isn't considered valid, it will be ignored.

For example:

> Going along with @Stuart Whitehead comments, right here is proof: "AttributeType::String does not apply any validation rules." Which is why that field was not getting populated.

[Check out this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8884/save-contact-form-data-to-database) I think it will have everything you are looking for.