# Craft CMS Plugin Save Record to DB from Variable

Tags: plugin-development, database, records

I am tearing my hair out with this!

So, I have a variable file setup as follows

```
 <?php
namespace Craft;

class TrackrVariable
{
    public function startTrace()
    {
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['trackr_sess'])):
            $sess = StringHelper::randomString(40, TRUE);
            $expire = time()+60*60*24*120; // 120 days
            setcookie('trackr_sess', $sess, $expire);
            $_COOKIE['trackr_sess'] = $sess;
        else:
            $sess = $_COOKIE['trackr_sess'];
        endif;

        $trace = new Trackr_TraceModel();
        $trace->entry_id = 1;
        $trace->sess_id = $sess;
        craft()->trackr_trace->saveTrace($trace);
    }
}
```

...and I am calling the function in my template using:

```
{{ craft.trackr.startTrace() }}
```

I create the model and set the attributes and hand off to a service. The model looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Trackr_TraceModel extends BaseModel
{
   public function rules()
    {
        // Are there any existing rules?
        $rules = parent::rules();

        // Make all attributes safe
        $rules[] = array(implode(',', array_keys($this->getAttributes())), 'safe');

        // Send it on outta here
        return $rules;
    }

    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return [
            'entry_id' => [
                 'type' => AttributeType::Number,
                 'required' => TRUE
             ],
             'sess_id' => [
                 'type' => AttributeType::String,
                 'required' => TRUE
             ]
        ];
    }
}
```

and the service looks like:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Trackr_TraceService extends BaseApplicationComponent
{

    protected $traceRecord;

    public function __construct($traceRecord = null)
    {
        $this->traceRecord = $traceRecord;
        if(is_null($this->traceRecord))
        {
            $this->traceRecord = Trackr_TraceRecord::model();
        }   
    }

    public function saveTrace(Trackr_TraceModel &$trace)
    {

        if ($id = $trace->getAttribute('id')) :
            if ($this->traceRecord->findByPk($id) === NULL):
                throw new Exception(Craft::t('Can\'t find trace with ID "{id}"', array('id' => $id)));
            endif;
        else:
            $this->traceRecord->create();
        endif;

        if ($trace->validate()):

            $dt = DateTimeHelper::currentTimeForDb();
            $attributes = array(
                'entry_id' => $trace->entry_id,
                'sess_id' => $trace->sess_id,
                'dateCreated' => $dt,
                'dateUpdated' =>$dt,
                'uid' => StringHelper::UUID(),
                'id' => 0
            );    
            foreach($attributes as $k => $v) $this->traceRecord->setAttribute($k,$v);

            if($this->traceRecord->save()):
                // update id on model (for new records)
                $trace->setAttribute('id', $this->traceRecord->getAttribute('id'));
                return TRUE;
            else:
                $model->addErrors($this->traceRecord->getErrors());
                return FALSE;
            endif;

        endif;
    }
}
```

In my mind, the service should be accepting the model, assigning it's attributes to the record and saving the record to the database. Currently, $record->save() is returning TRUE and therefore passing the conditional but no record is created in the dataset, no errors, no trace of any issues whatsoever!

At first I though it might be a 'safe validation' issue as outlined in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/8895/3968) but, as far as I am aware, I am following all of the advice there.

All I want to be able to do is create a random string, store it in a cookie, as use that cookie to track resources that users view by storing the entry IDs in a table.

If I print out the record and the model separately, the data is being assigned to the attributes just fine, and the cookie bit works.

Please help!
Dan

**EDIT**

The Record file looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Trackr_TraceRecord extends BaseRecord
{
    public function getTableName()
    {
        return 'trackr_trace';
    }

    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'entry_id' => AttributeType::Number,
            'sess_id' => AttributeType::String
        );
    }
    public function defineIndexes()
    {
        return array(
            array('columns' => array('sess_id'), 'unique' => TRUE),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of the current class.
     *
     * @return BaseRecord
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $class = get_class($this);
        $record = new $class();
        return $record;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is `$record = $this->traceRecord;`.  Try doing all of your record related operations on `$this->traceRecord` directly instead of copying it to `$record`.

Comment: Thanks Brad but unfortunately this didn't make any difference, I have updated the example code in this post to reflect the changes.

Comment: Are you able to share your record code at all?

Comment: Added the record into the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m seeing a few issues with this:

- Service classes aren’t created with any arguments*, so the `$traceRecord` argument in your `__construct()` method is pointless.
- Setting `$this->traceRecord` to `Trackr_TraceRecord::model()` is really weird. When you call `::model()` you’re getting a “meta” version of your record class, which should only be used to call things like `find()`, and those functions will return the actual record instances. (It’s basically just an awkward workaround for the fact that Yii 1 didn’t require PHP 5.3+, so they couldn’t rely on Late Static Bindings support, which would have made it possible to do things like `MyServiceClass::find()` directly - as you can in Yii 2.) Point is, you shouldn’t be storing a reference to the meta record returned by `::model()`.
- `$trace->getAttribute('id')` implies that your Trackr_TraceModel class has an `id` attribute, but it doesn’t, unless you didn’t post all of your model attributes code.
- Calling `if ($this->traceRecord->findByPk($id) === NULL)` works as a conditional statement, but it looks like your logic is assuming that if a record was actually found, that `$this->traceRecord` would be set to that new record. That won’t actually be the case unless you write `$this->traceRecord = ...`.
- Records don’t have a `create()` method. I’m not sure why that’s not throwing a PHP error for you. Did you add that method yourself? If you want to create a new record instance, you should be typing `$this->traceRecord = new Trackr_TraceRecord();`

I’d suggest you remove your service’s `__construct()` method, and also its protected `$traceRecord` property. Then update its `saveTrace()` method to the following:

```
public function saveTrace(Trackr_TraceModel &$trace)
{

    if ($id = $trace->getAttribute('id'))
    {
        $traceRecord = Trackr_TraceRecord::model()->findById($id);

        if (!$traceRecord)
        {
            throw new Exception(Craft::t('Can\'t find trace with ID "{id}"', array('id' => $id)));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $traceRecord = new Trackr_TraceRecord();
    }

    if ($trace->validate())
    {
        $dt = DateTimeHelper::currentTimeForDb();
        $attributes = array(
            'entry_id' => $trace->entry_id,
            'sess_id' => $trace->sess_id,
            'dateCreated' => $dt,
            'dateUpdated' =>$dt,
            'uid' => StringHelper::UUID(),
            'id' => 0
        );

        foreach($attributes as $k => $v)
        {
            $traceRecord->setAttribute($k,$v);
        }

        if ($traceRecord->save())
        {
            // update id on model (for new records)
            $trace->setAttribute('id', $traceRecord->getAttribute('id'));
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $model->addErrors($traceRecord->getErrors());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

* Unless you’re creating an instance of your class in some other way besides calling `craft()->trackr_trace`, but you shouldn’t be.

Comment: Brandon, you are a Gentleman and a Scholar! This worked perfectly. Reading through your explanation makes perfect sense. I'm still a noob to Yii coming from Laravel I'm still learning the nuances. Thank you again!