# Model values assignment issue

Tags: models, attribute

I am setting attributes on my record using a models' attributes (that has validated successfully). I cannot figure out why the values aren't assigned. I can manually assign each one but that's redundant.

```
// Set attributes
// Massive assignment will only be made for fields which have passed some explicit validation rule.
if ($model->validate())
{
    $purchaseRecord->setAttributes($model->getAttributes());
    var_dump($model->snipInvoiceNumber); // works
    var_dump($purchaseRecord->snipInvoiceNumber); // null value
    $purchaseRecord->snipInvoiceNumber = $model->snipInvoiceNumber; // works
}
```

UPDATE:
Per comments on this thread I looped through and set the attributes individually. Anyone have insight on why setAttributes didn't work? 
[Save contact form data to database](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8884/save-contact-form-data-to-database)

This is what I used instead of setAttributes (plural).

```
foreach ($model->getAttributes() as $key => $value ) {
    $purchaseRecord->setAttribute($key, $value);
}
```

Comment: It would seem while several of these columns will not be assigned values successfully a handful of others are working fine. Not sure if the issue is related but the ones working are all ones defined in my record defineRelations().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a second parameter  in your `setAttributes()` function. This parameter is true per default and checks if the attribute is `safe` so you either have to declare all safe attributes in your records rules or you set the parameter to false.

Comment: Thank you Robin! That was precisely the issue! I'll have to learn more about what the 'safe' rules are but in the meantime false fixed it up.

Comment: The craft docs on setAttributes did not have the value but looking at yii docs I see it http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#setAttributes-detail

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love Craft and I love to work with it but the online documentation is pretty bad. Most things are well explained in the code, so you should look there first but nearly 70% is not even mentioned in the online documentation. As for the safe attributes, you can learn more about that here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#safe-attributes